# How to open IIS through RPA UIPath

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-activity, uipath-api

I want to open IIS through uipath, but whenever I use the "Open Application" activity for open IIS below errors are shown. So, what workflow I have to make to open IIS through uipath?

[image]

Comment: When I search for uipath from the start menu of my system, it does not show uipath studio, which I have to run as an administrator

Comment: Please delete that comment and add it to your Question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important things to realise in UiPath is that there are many many ways to achieve the same thing. Each one has it's Pro's and Con's but don't work in every situation.

Some alternatives to try

1. Command Prompt

   - Open run (Send hot key `Windows Key + R`
   - Type `CMD` and click `run`
   - type `start inetmgr` and then send hotkey `enter`
2. Clicking

   - Use clicks to navigate to IIS, or put a shortcut on the desktop and click on it
3. Start Process

   - Use the start process activity, pass in the path of IIS `C:\...\...\IIS Link`

This UiPath forum is also a good place to look for help https://forum.uipath.com

Comment: If I want to open IIS from another system, do I have to install something on that system

Comment: What do you mean by another system?

Comment: means, suppose there are two people one is in x--country and other is in y-country. x-country's person want to access y-country's people computer